# I want to customize the frequency with which sites appear in my iOS feed

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Feature request: I want to customize my iOS feed. For example, I am not interested in role playing games, but I am very Interested in aviation.

Edit:  For clarity, I’m talking about the top of this image.  I don’t speak French nor have I joined that community.

[image: image of feed]

Comment: Work on the app has been put on hold indefinetly back in 2017, so dont expect anything to happen with your feature-request anytime soon.

Comment: Isn't the feed affected by the sites you've joined? You don't have an RPG.SE account, so you shouldn't see anything from it in the feed...

Comment: @Glorfindel, nope. And that may be a good thing. A blacklist would be better than a whitelist IMO.

Comment: Are you talking about the top block in the feed (which is the Hot Network Questions list, which is indeed not filtered) or the rest of the feed, which (in my experience) only shows content from sites where I am the most active.